# Can’t remove items from a React state collection

Tags: reactjs

I have these two methods defined in my React component:

```
handleAddMetric() {
    const metricKey = prompt('Name/key of metric');
    const newMetricItem = {
        name: metricKey,
        value: 100
    }
    let newMetrics = {};
    newMetrics[metricKey] = newMetricItem;
    const updatedMetrics = Object.assign({}, this.state.metrics, newMetrics);
    this.setState({ metrics: updatedMetrics });
}

handleRemoveMetric(keyName) {
    let updatedMetrics = this.state.metrics;
    delete updatedMetrics[keyName];
    console.log('handleRemoveMetric', this, keyName, updatedMetrics);
    this.setState({ metrics: updatedMetrics });
}
```

Adding new values to `this.state.metrics` works fine, but deleting:

```
<button onClick={this.handleRemoveMetric.bind(this, key)}>Delete</button>
```

...calls my `handleRemoveMetric` function but doesn’t update the collection.

I first it was some issue with `this` but that doesn’t seem to be the case.

Any ideas?

**Update:** The console output is:

```
handleRemoveMetric Metrics {props: Object, context: Object, refs: Object, updater: Object, state: Object…}componentWillUnmount: function ()context: Objectprops: Objectref: Objectrefs: ObjectsetState: function (data, cb)state: Objectupdater: Object_reactInternalInstance: ReactCompositeComponentWrapperisMounted: (...)replaceState: (...)__proto__: ReactComponent
"myMetricKey"
Object {MRR: Object, moneyInBank: Object, wow: Object}
```

...so at least the collection is updated locally.

Comment: keyName is proper ? and result of `console.log('handleRemoveMetric', keyName, updatedMetrics);` contains the deleted key ?

Comment: @MayankShukla Good point. I included the console output above. It looks as if the collection is updated locally but not in `state`.

Comment: You need to copy it over to a new object. `const metrics = { ...this.state.metrics, [keyName]: undefined }; this.setState({ metrics });` should work.

Comment: how you are checking that state is not getting updated ?

Comment: @vijayst Thank you! That did it! I changed to `const updatedMetrics = { ...this.state.metrics, [keyName]: null };` because I'm using Firebase, but now it works. Please add an answer and I'll upvote you.

Comment: @TomSöderlund Glad to know it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy it over to a new object.

```
const metrics = { 
  ...this.state.metrics, 
  [keyName]: null 
}; 
this.setState({ metrics });
```

should work.